# Regex: VBA : Evaluation of Expression with Conditions

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I am trying to extract a cell number from the formula expression (in vba) which I need to replace by another cell number. eg: I have the following formulae in different cells "=AL82+L8+L82", "=L8+L82" and "=AL82+L8"  . I have to change "L8" in each of the formulae to "L9". I am new to Regex and was trying the following expression in regex pattern:

```
"(?=[^A-Z])([L8])(?=[^0-9])"
```

However only 8 is changed to L9. Please assist me with the error.

Thanks

Comment: If the L can only be preceded by either a char A-Z `+` or `=` you could use a capturing group `([A-Z+=])L8` and replace with group 1 followed by L9 `$1L9`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/ViOrfE/1

Comment: Please update your post with your desired output for the 3 examples you provided

Comment: The desired output is as follows:
"=AL82+L8+L82" output -> "=AL82+L9+L82"
"=L8+L82"  output  ->   "=L9+L82"  
"=AL82+L8" output -> "=AL82+L9"

Comment: Have your tried the `Replace` function? `rng.Formula = Replace(rng.Formula, "L8", "L9")`

Comment: @AshutoshGoenka Did the pattern work out?

Comment: @Thefourthbird
Thanks for sharing the pattern. I am getting the following output:
"=AL82+L8+L82" output -> "=AL92+L8+L82" 
"=L8+L82" output -> "=L9+L82"
 "=AL82+L8" output -> "=AL92+L8" 

I'm not sure if I have implemented it properly. Here is the code:

    Dim RegEx As Object, MyString As String
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With RegEx
      .Pattern = "([A-Z+=])L8"
    End With
    
    Debug.Print (Range("N10").Formula)
    If RegEx.Test(Range("N10").Formula) Then
        Debug.Print RegEx.Replace(Range("N10").Formula, "$1L9")
    End If

Comment: @SuperSymmetry
Yes, it just replaces the 8 to L9 in this expression "=AL82+LL9+L82" is the output

Comment: Try setting the global property to true `RegEx.Global = True`

Comment: @Thefourthbird
 Getting the following:
"=AL82+L8" output -> "=AL92+L9" ....."=AL82+L8+L82" output -> "=AL92+L9+L92" and 
"=L8+L82" -> "=L9+L92". I need to change only when only if the cell is L8.. Is it possible to add some more restrictions

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/MLvJVq/1 Or even more restrictive `([+=])L8(?!\d)` https://regex101.com/r/ppOUDb/1

Comment: This is perfect!!! Thanks a lot..

Comment: The first or the second one?

Comment: @Thefourthbird   Both!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture either plus or an equals sign in a capturing group.

Then Match L8 and assert using a negative lookahead, that the 8 is not directly followed by a digit.

In the replacement use group 1 followed by L9: `$1L9`

```
([+=])L8(?!\d)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eMH2hT/1)

Comment: In any such simple formulas it's relatively safe just to search and replace `\bL8\b` I'd say.

Comment: @JvdV You would know better than me about that. I added the character class and the negative lookahead to be sure about the restrictions.